# insert `id` autoincrement primary key field explicitly in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am migrating an old data into laravel.

What i want is to keep the previous ids same in the new table
where i have a default `$table->increments(id)` field.

Is there a way in laravel that i can explicitly insert this id field?

As i am unable to do it using eloquent model `create` method :

```
User::create([
'id' => 123456,
'first_name' => 'john',
'last_name' => 'doe'
])
```

Is it even possible in there?

Comment: what do you want, auto increment beign with 123456?

Comment: it could be any and from there its starts auto incrementing whatever the last value will be, how can i explicitly insert in id field.?

Comment: Kinda fighting against the purpose of an autoincrement field there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem must be in the User model. Open the User.php file and modify the `$fillable` variable. Add `id` to the array. The `$fillable` variable tells Eloquent which fields to protect from a mass-assignment like the one you are doing (mass assignment meaning you're setting all the values at once in your insert). So even if you specify `id` like you did in your create() call Eloquent will ignore whatever value you have set because that field is not part of the `$fillable` fields.

So have that variable like:

`protected $fillable = ['id', 'first_name', 'last_name'];`

and you should be good to go (also taking into account that you have not left any fields empty which according to the user migration cannot be null)