# Change laravel default user id

Tags: laravel

I am wondering if there is an easy way to assign my own (random integer) id to the user when sign up instead of default auto increment id?

I use laravel 6+ with default authentication module.

This is the code in RegisterController.php that I tried but it does not work:

```
/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @return User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'id'=$my_random_value, //I added this line
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

Comment: Post your code?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Having auto-increment is an easy way to avoid duplicate numbers.

Comment: If you're trying to hide your user count, consider a UUID.

Comment: @bumperbox I am concerning about hackers when they learn to attack an account. The auto increment provides them a chance to attack the next account by adding up 1 to the previous user id.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35253153/insert-id-autoincrement-primary-key-field-explicitly-in-laravel-5-2

Comment: You better use `UUID` instead. Example of uuid : `123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-556642440000`

Comment: Using a random number is not there same as making your system secure. It's only a matter of time until they discover a random id.

Comment: That is exactly the point to buy time

Comment: A random number will stop someone fooling around trying to guess another users id. It won't stop a determined hacker. I would go with the uuid suggestion that was made. They are harder to guess.

Comment: That is absolutely right. I just want to prevent chicken hackers! we practically cannot stop black hats!

Answer (score 0):

auto increment id or unique column is an important factor in database management, especially on eloquent relationships.

but if you want a custom attributes id
just create an `accessor` or `mutators`
https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class User extends Model
{
    /**
     * Get the user's random id.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getCustomId()
    {
        return uniqid();
    }
}
```

then you can call the custom attributes.

```
$user = App\User::find(1);

$firstName = $user->custom_id;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. I do not think that this answer perfectly matches my need. I need to set the id at the begining once the user registered. Please see my update to the post.

Comment: I think you need to add it in a fillable variable in the model.
to whitelist the column
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent#mass-assignment